# Failed to converge in 100 iterations for gmdistribution with 5 components

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, gmm

I'm doing clustering via GMM in MATLAB. The warning is **"Failed to converge in 100 iterations for gmdistribution with 10 components"**
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the results are good enough. Maybe it would have converged at iteration 101, then the result at 100 would be pretty much the same.

Make sure your data is not degenerate.